# How do I position menu items in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-menu

My `ActionBar` currently consists of a logo and some text. I done this by inflating the following `menu`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context="com.example.sv_laptop.myapp.Register">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/signup"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:title="Icon"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

However, it shows both items on the far right hand side of the `ActionBar` together.  What I want to achieve is the logo being on the far left hand side and the **text/title** being in the middle.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Another problem is that it displays the image too small - would highly appreciate it if somebody could give me a walkthrough on how to scale it.

**This is how I'm inflating the menu**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.menu_register_name, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Highly grateful for any help!

Edit:

action_bar_layout

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"/>
```

The problem is that now the logo displays in the center and the text displays on the far right. When I give paddingRight to the logo (ImageView) the text disappears, but it does move to the right. If I add paddingRight to the text it disappears again. I have also tried setting paddingRight in the LinearLayout and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior which you are getting is default behavior of android, however what you are looking is default behavior of iOS.

If you want to achieve that, you have to implement custom xml.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

Here you need to create actionbar.xml in your layout and inflate it.

Comment: Hello I've tried to use this, it looks better but its still not how I want it. Can you check my edit? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `ToolBar` add your View's to `ToolBar` like normal ViewGroup

[Good Example how to set ToolBar](http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example)

**example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:visibility="GONE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```